# MutationObserver works only with FF

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, opera, mutation-observers

I have a DIV with id='obsah_popis' (which basically hold all the page content) and this div is filled dynamically upon request (by clicking on menu buttons, photogalery buttons etc.) so its height is not constant but changes overtime as different objects go in or out (loaded in/out).

I need to monitor its actual height for my custom build (coded) scroller which recalculate its height and everything necessary around it according to that height value.

I made a MutationObserver for this reason that **works great...but ONLY IN Firefox** (46+) - when I run it under Chrome (63) or Opera (50) it does not work at all.

My code for the observer part looks like this (for the purpose of testing I only added alert() to fire up letting me know it was triggered):

```
var test = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
    alert();
    //resizeSkrolerHandle();            
});
test.observe(document.querySelector('#obsah_popis'), {
    attributes:true,
    childList:true,
    characterData:true,
    subtree:true
});
```

BTW strangelly enough (at least for me) this other MutationObserver I run at the same place (just underneath my not functioning one) work perfectly in all browsers:

```
var bbb = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
    document.getElementById("parallax_pozadie").style.top = document.getElementById("parallax_static").style.top = (document.getElementById("skroler").getBoundingClientRect().top * -1) * scrollSpeedMultiply + "px";
});
bbb.observe(document.querySelector('#skroler'), {
    attributes:true,
    childList:false
});
```

The only difference I see there is the fact that this working one is actually fired up by **MANUAL INPUT** (dragging of my custom scroller) whereas that non-working one is supposed to be fired up programmatically.

**Does anyone know the reason and possible solution to this?**

Comment: Debug it. Make sure there are no errors that stop execution of your code before it reaches the observer. Make sure document.querySelector('#obsah_popis') returns the actual element, not null.

Comment: Well it *was* behind a "Webkit" prefix but my version of Chrome has both.

Comment: @wOxxOm but interestingly my other MutationObserver works OK with all the browsers (see my update code in my post) + how can it be 'broken' when it works under FF?

Comment: @Pointy BTW the solution that you've already removed - therefore I am informing you here - does not work: it still does nothing to Chrome nor Opera, exactly as my original code...

Comment: Are you saying your `alert()` doesn't run in Chrome at all? "does not work at all" is not very clear.

Comment: Why do you expect a mutation event to occur when the elements' height changes? Can you create a stacksnippets to reproduce the issue? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @loganfsmyth "_I made a MutationObserver for this reason that works great...but ONLY IN Firefox (46+) - when I run it under Chrome (63) or Opera (50) it does not work at all._" - I thought that from this sentence it is clear **I am talking about the MutationObserver that is not working at all* in that particular instance cos at another it runs just fine

Comment: @guest271314 it is explained in the post... + no, I cannot as this is all interconnected with lots of other files, alone it would do nothing or better said just alone it should work as by sight there seems to be nothing wrong with that code, it just don't run under Chorme nor Opera, in FF it runs OK

Comment: An explanation is not a reproduction

Comment: see abov why I cannot reproduce it

Comment: What is the expected result of the question?

Comment: "does not work" is not a description. What _part_ doesn't work? Does the alert not run? Does the code in `resizeSkrolerHandle` not work? We don't have enough information to answer this in any way.

Comment: @guest271314 this sentence is in the post approximately in the middle: **Does anyone know the reason and possible solution to this?**

Comment: @loganfsmyth MutationObserver does not run at all in Chrome nor Opera - what more or how much detailed do I have to tell it? What more can I say about it except that it does not work, like it is not triggered, not "fired up" cos for example that alert() that is inside it (MutationObserver) does not pop up but alert(), as such is working...is this clear enough now? :-)

Comment: As of yet the problem that you are describing has not been reproduced. You can help to resolve your own inquiry by including all of the HTML and JavaScript and CSS that you are experiencing the issue using at the Question, for viewers of the Question to be able to reproduce, verify, and attempt to fix or suggest an alternative approach which can possibly be a solution to your Question.

Comment: @guest271314 I cannot reproduce, I already told it to you several times - I do get your point (that is you cannot help more if you cannot lok at the actual code) but please, stop repeating it constantly: you are of no help, if you cannot help for whatever reason it is OK and understood, no problem, but please, do not flood this post and do not react anymore in this style, I understand you and I cannot give you that example you want, that is it

Comment: You have to understand that **we have to be able to reproduce your problem in order to help you**. @guest271314 is entirely right. With what you gave us, it is [impossible for us to reproduce the problem](https://jsfiddle.net/s5qwg348/) and thus to help you, making **your question pointless**.  So as hard as it may seem to you, create an [MCVE], by doing this, you'll probably find out what the problem is.

Comment: And btw, a MutationObserver is most often the sign of an x-y problem. Instead of listening to these changes, tweak the code that generates these changes so that you function that should be called be from this code directly (e.g `obsah_popis.append(XXX); resizeSkrolerHandle();`) The only times I had to use a MutationObserver was for debugin purposes, but it never made its way to production.

Comment: @Kaiido yes, I know, if you would read my answer right you would see I wrote I do understand his point but I cannot make a simple example as my code - each part of it - depends mostly on each other so I would end up with literally several hundreds maybe thousands of lines of code, all i was saying was to top repeating it constantly as I got it but cannot provide what he wants

Comment: BTW as of now I was told by other StackOverflow user that what I need is more likely a ResizeObserver, not MutationObserver as all my div attributes are done strictly via CSS so MutationObserver is unable pick them (at least that is how I understood what he was saying)